# Solving the Wave Equation With Boundary Conditions $u(0,t)=0, \ u_x(1,t)=0$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Using separation of variables, construct the general solution of the wave equation $$u_{tt}=u_{xx},$$ for $0<x<1, \ t>0$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t)=0$ and $u_x(1,t)=0$ for $t>0$ and initial condition $u(x,0)=0.$

My attempt:

We assume the solution takes the form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t).$ Hence, $$\frac{T''}{T}=\frac{X''}{X}=\lambda \ \ \ (\text{$\lambda$ is a separation constant}).$$
First consider $X''-\lambda X=0$. The cases where $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda>0$ lead to the trivial solution. I am having trouble with the case where $\lambda<0$. In this case, $$X(x)=A\cos(wx)+B\sin(wx) \ \ A,B\in\mathbb{R}.$$
The boundary condition $$u(0,t)=0\implies X(0)=0\implies A=0.$$

> My question is, how do I deal with $u_x(1,t)=0$?
>   I know that this implies $X'(1)=0$, so does this mean $Bw\cos(w)=0?$ If so, $B\neq 0$ and $w\neq 0$ (as the solution would be trivial). So does this mean $$w=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi, \ n=0,1,2,3...?$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It means that there are an infinite number of "eigenvalues" and that the solution, instead of being a simple product, X(x)T(t), is an infinite sum, $\sum_{n= 0}^\infty X_n(x)T_n(t)$ where $X_n(x)= Acos((\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi)x)+ Bsin((\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi)x)$ and $T_n(t)$ is a solution to $T''= (\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi)^2T$.

Comment: So $w=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$? Meaning that the eigenvalues take the form $\lambda=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\right)^2$?

Comment: Well, that was what **you** said in your first post!

Comment: Which I made clear that I was unsure about. It is dependent on the correctness of my interpretation of the boundary condition $u_x(1,t)=0$. I will put this in yellow for reference.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. For a non-trivial solution, $B \ne 0$. You also already dealt with the case where $\lambda = 0 \implies w \ne 0$. So that leaves you to solve $$\cos(w) = 0 \implies w = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$$ which are the square root of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Just quickly, is $n$ restricted to $\mathbb{Z^+}$? In my original post, I took $n=0,1,2...$.